# grep a number after a specific word | bash

Tags: bash

I have a lines, such as:

```
calc addr thc 589 boil_con 192.168.0.2/24 hoi DNS 10.0.34.5 bio
```

And I need to get only first IP, and I'm trying to do it like this :

```
line1="calc addr thc 589 boil_con 192.168.0.2/24 hoi DNS 10.0.34.5 bio"
echo $line1 | grep -oP "boil_con\s+\K\w+"
```

But it seems "." is considered as some sort of breaking point, how to bypass this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dot is not part of the `\w` class, but you can always define character class that includes both `\w` and dot:

```
grep -oP "boil_con\s+\K[\w.]+"
                       ~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP 'boil_con\s\K.*?[^/]+'
192.168.0.2
```

Small variant from another answer by Choroba.  This will ignore `boil_con`and print till first `/`.